# Move cursor to specific cell in other worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I put a value in "Sheet1" cell "J2". On running the macro I want cursor to move to "Sheet2" Column "B" and row  number as per value put in "Sheet1" cell "J2". Please suggest vba code for the same. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub moveToCell()
    Dim intRow As Integer

    intRow = Sheet1.Range("J2").Value

    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Range("B" & intRow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx a lot, it works..

Comment: Here is again a problem. if i rename worksheets i.e. "Sheet1" as "Denom" and "Sheet2" as "Scroll" then it doesn't work and message pops "object required". Please help on the issue..

Comment: Instead of Sheet1 or Sheet2 in the code above you can change them to Sheets("Denom") and Sheets("Scroll") respectively.

Comment: here it goes.... thanx..........